# Protractor: ElementArrayFinder to generic array

Tags: javascript, protractor

Is it possible to convert the `ElementArrayFinder` returned by the results of `element.all(....)` into a generic array?

The goal is to store the elements in the array and add more elements to them from result of another `element.all()` using `push()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can *extend `ElementArrayFinder`* and add an `extend()` method concatenating the arrays of internal web elements of both array finders:

```
protractor.ElementArrayFinder.prototype.extend = function(finder) {
    var self = this;
    var getWebElements = function() {
        return self.getWebElements().then(function(parentWebElements) {
            return finder.getWebElements().then(function(newWebElements) {
                return parentWebElements.concat(newWebElements);
            });
        });
    };
    return new protractor.ElementArrayFinder(this.browser_, getWebElements, this.locator_);
};
```

Usage:

```
var arr1 = $$(".myclass");
var arr2 = $$(".someotherclass");

var newArr = arr1.extend(arr2);
expect(newArr.getText()).toEqual(["text1", "text2", "text3"]);
```

Tested, works for me in a simple test case.